# \ContinuedFloat does not work with memoir class, why?

Tags: memoir

In the `memoir` class when I use `\ContinuedFloat`, the figures get marked in subfigures such as (a), (b), (c),(d), (e), (f) and in the next page it continues as (a), (b), (c), (d), (e), (f) again in the next page instead of (g), (h), (i), (j), (k), (l). But in the `report` class it works fine and there is no problem.

I have also written an example code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\begin{document}

\section{Figure Arrangements}

\begin{figure}

\vspace{-12cm}

\subfigure[a]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_01.jpg}
    \label{fig:fig1}}

\subfigure[b]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_02.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig2}}    
    
\subfigure[c]{
    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_03.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig3}}

\subfigure[d]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_04.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig4}}    

\subfigure[e]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_05.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig5}}    

\subfigure[f]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_06.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig6}}        
\end{figure}    

%% The below figures will come in next page

\begin{figure}

\ContinuedFloat    

\subfigure[g]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_07.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig7}}

\subfigure[h]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_08.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig8}}

\subfigure[i]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_09.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig9}}

\subfigure[j]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_10.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig10}}\hspace{-0.25cm}    

\subfigure[k]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_11.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig11}}    

\subfigure[l]{

    \centering
        \subfloat\includegraphics[scale = 1]{myfig_12.jpg}
        \label{fig:fig12}}    

\caption{Figure Arrangements}

\label{fig:all_figures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have also attached an image of the output with `memoir` class in order to make it clear. Also you could see in the second page that (a)g,(b)h,(c)i,(d)j,(e)k,(f)l all rounded with red color. It should be like (g)g,(h)h,(i)i,(j)j,(k)k,(l)l which is the correct order. If I put `\documentclass{report}` instead of `\documentclass{memoir}`, the correct order comes true. But I need this arrangement in `memoir`. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `subfigure` is outdated since quite a time. Please consider using `subfig` or `subcaption`. The following should work in `memoir` *and* `report`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\begin{document}
\section{Figure Arrangements}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_01.jpg}
        \caption{a}\label{fig:fig1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_02.jpg}
        \caption{b}\label{fig:fig2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_03.jpg}
        \caption{c}\label{fig:fig3}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_04.jpg}
        \caption{d}\label{fig:fig4}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_05.jpg}
        \caption{e}\label{fig:fig5}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_06.jpg}
        \caption{f}\label{fig:fig6}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 

% The below figures will come in next page
\begin{figure}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_07.jpg}
        \caption{g}\label{fig:fig7}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_08.jpg}
        \caption{h}\label{fig:fig8}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_09.jpg}
        \caption{i}\label{fig:fig9}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_10.jpg}
        \caption{j}\label{fig:fig10}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_11.jpg}
        \caption{k}\label{fig:fig11}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{myfig_12.jpg}
        \caption{l}\label{fig:fig12}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I tried it, but the code given above didnot work for me in the memoir class again. I tried even with the package subfig but of no use. I have changed the \caption{a} as \subcaption{a} and I changed in the same manner for all. But in vain. My entire writing has stopped because of that. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: @vinaymathi "didnot work for me" is nothing I can work with. Please compile only my MWE. If this does not work, we will have to check if your system is up to date or you will have to provide the errors you are seeing.

Comment: @ LaRiFaRi - your  code works very fine individually but when I implement this in my actual code it did not work because there are so many errors that comes during my output and I have no patientence to correct it now. Another code  I have written from the idea of one of the persons in the tex exchange which  works fine with my code but with only problem with the caption which I am going to post now. If you could answer it would be more helpful to me as I have less time to prepare my reports.